# searching sql DB table for japanese terms

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns that allow for different language formats (using nvarchar) and the problem is that when I try to search for these terms; particularly Japanese/Chinese terms, the typical select statement does not work

```
select * from jtable where searchterm = 'ろくでなし'
```

It will return 0 which is incorrect since it is definitely in the table. Someone mentioned using cast(....) but not sure how to do this.

Comment: ろくでなし is not really a nice word, isn't it?)

Comment: sorry that was impolite of me but it really is a term in my table

Comment: this should be very interesting project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need an N to make the string literal unicode.

```
select * from jtable where searchterm = N'ろくでなし'
```

Without the N the 'ろくでなし' is implicit varchar and is seen as '?????'

See my related answer about khmer text for examples of why: [Khmer Unicode, English and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 results in questionmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383523/khmer-unicode-english-and-microsoft-sql-server-2008-results-in-questionmarks/6383641#6383641)